# Design flow for Point Of Sale software for multiple location

Tags: php, mysql, security

I want to design POS application in php,mysql for multiple store location which are internally connected with each other. Sub Admin (each store manager) can manage store with new order placing, taking care of customers and tracking inventory. 
Super Admin can watch each store activities in details like each store's sale, staff details, inventory etc.
What would be the best design flow for this? Cloud is best solution in my view but what would happen when there is no internet connection or slow connection. Is it possible to run desktop version on each PC which can interact with main server time to time. I am little confused here. This is big project so security is also other concern. 
So in short want to design an application which can run stand alone and also can run with cloud.
Your help will be much appreciated..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If they're all interconnected anyway, can't you host the software on a web server on their network?  It would still be behind their firewall and if you're feeling paranoid, you could keep a copy on an in-store server at each location that syncs with the network one.  This would keep everything private and still provide a fail-safe, and you don't have to worry about setting up PHP on each terminal or packaging your interface as an app.  The only hoop to jump through would be getting permission to set up a network server that runs PHP, but it shouldn't be too big of a deal.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion. What do you say about running whole application on cloud? Here speed and security is my concern. Which cloud hosting is better? Thanks again